# Script in if-up.d appears to be running 3 times. Only want it to run once

Tags: linux, networking, debian, openvpn, debian-wheezy

I have a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d` to connect to my VPN on startup. It appears that the script is running three times and therefore connecting to my VPN three times. After startup, looking at `sudo ifconfig` verifies that, in fact, three tunnels have been created. Also, I can see all three openvpn daemons when looking at the output from `ps aux`. How do I make sure it only runs once? And why is it running more than once? I am running Debian 7.3.

The contents of `/etc/network/if-up.d/connectvpn` are:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --keepalive 5 30 --config /etc/openvpn/configs/bitterroot.conf
```

Thank you for your help!
Jeff

Comment: Why aren't you checking the passed arguments?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by checking the passed arguments. Could you explain further? Thank you.

Comment: `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams There are no passed arguments to the actual script `/etc/network/if-up.d/connectvpn`. It just runs as-is w/o arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, `ifup` / `ifdown` does not guarantee that your script only runs once. Thus your script has to be idempotent; that is, contain its own logic not to establish a tunnel that already exists. The best way, of course, is to start the script by actually checking if the tunnel is already there:

```sh
# Exit if network device "tun0" exists.
ip link show dev tun0 >/dev/null 2>&1 && exit 0
```

Additionally, the scripts in `if-up.d` etc. run for every interface that is brought up.
As Jeff correctly observes, the `if-*.d` scripts receive no arguments specifying e.g. which interface is coming up.

Instead, per the [interfaces(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/interfaces.5.html) man page:

```
   There  exists  for  each  of  the  above  mentioned options a directory
   /etc/network/if-<option>.d/ [...]

   All of these commands have access to the  following  environment  vari‐
   ables.

   IFACE  physical name of the interface being processed

   LOGICAL
          logical name of the interface being processed

  [... and more ...]
```

The solution is to start the script with a check for the correct `IFACE` value, e.g.:

```sh
# Exit if we're not starting "eth0".
[ "$IFACE" = 'eth0' ] || exit 0
```

Otherwise, the script will run for every network device, including `lo`, at which point it may be too early to establish a tunnel.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
if [ "$MODE" != start ]; then
        exit 0
fi
```

to your script.

In general, to debug things like this it's customary to first make your script consist only of something like

```
#!bin/sh
echo "$@" >/tmp/blah
set >>/tmp/blah
```

and inspect the contents of `/tmp/blah` after the script is run to get the rough idea of what arguments the script is passed (if any) and what it sees in its environment when runs.

Comment: Thank you, @kostix. This worked for debugging, unfortunately for me it appears this was not the problem I was having...